# How to periodically schedule a same activity when the previous one is still excuting

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-swf

My goal is to have an workflow which periodically (every 30 seconds) add a  same activity (doing nothing but sleep for 1 minute) to the taskList. Also I have multiple machines hosting activity workers to poll the taskList simultaneously. When the activity got scheduled, one of the workers can poll it and execute.

I tried to use a cron decorator to create a DynamicActivityClient and use the DynamicActivityClient.scheduleActivity() to schedule the activity periodically. However, it seems the the activity will not be scheduled until the last activity is finished. In my case, the activity got scheduled every 1 minute rather than 30 seconds which I set in the cron pattern.

The package structure is almost the same as aws sdk sample code: [cron](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/cron)
Is there any other structure recommended to achieve this?  I am very much new to SWF.Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cron decorator internally relies on [AsyncScheduledExecutor](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/interceptors/AsyncScheduledExecutor.java) which is by design written to wait for all asynchronous code in the invoked method to complete before calling the cron again. So the behavior you are witnessing is expected. The workaround is to not invoke activity from the code under cron, but from the code in the different scope. Something like:

```
// This is a field
Settable<Void> invokeNextActivity = new Settable<>();

void executeCron() {
    scheduledExecutor.execute(new AsyncRunnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() throws Throwable {
            // Instead of executing activity here just unblock
            // its execution in a different scope.
            invokeNextActivity.set(null);
        }
    });
    // Recursive loop with each activity invocation 
    // gated on invokeNextActivity
    executeActivityLoop(invokeNextActivity);
}

@Asynchronous
void executeActivityLoop(Promise waitFor) {
   activityClient.executeMyActivityOnce();
   ivnokeNextActivity = new Settable<>();
   executeActivityLoop(ivnokeNextActivity);
}
```

I recommend reading TryCatchFinally documentation to get understanding of error handling and scopes.

Another option is to rewrite *AsyncScheduledExecutor* to invoke  *invoked.set(lastInvocationTime)* not from the *doFinally* but immediately after calling the *command.run()*

Comment: Hi Maxim, thanks for your suggestion. Is the "scheduledExecutor" in your code an instance of AsyncScheduledExecutor?  My code is like: `                long startTime = clock.currentTimeMillis();
Date expiration = new Date(startTime + cronOptions.getContinueAsNewAfterSeconds() * SECOND);
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(cronOptions.getTimeZone());
CronInvocationSchedule cronSchedule = new CronInvocationSchedule(cronOptions.getCronExpression(), expiration, tz);             
AsyncScheduledExecutor scheduledExecutor = new AsyncScheduledExecutor(cronSchedule, clock);  `

Comment: Yes, I copied it from the cron with retry example

Comment: Hi Maxim, I think the scheduledExecutor.execute does not work correctly: it does not running periodically. I insert a print statement System.out.println(clock.currentTimeMillis()) inside the run() method, it prints infinite timestamp continuously. Is the executor expected to run a cron job or just run  continuously? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the reason is: when the executeActivityLoop() got called recursively, the startCron() method also got executed (I put a print statement in starCron to show when it got called), so another scheduleExecutor got created. I tried the periodicworkflow example, it seems the startPeriodicWorkflow() also got called when the recursive call in the @Asynchronous method happens.

Comment: My guess is that asynchronous methods are not executed asynchronously due to invalid AspectJ setup. Try using Task directly instead of Asynchronous annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You may do so by writing a much simpler workflow code and using workflow clock and timer. Refer to the example in the link below. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/executioncontext.html

Also remember one thing. The maximum number of events allowed in a workflow execution is 25000. So the cron job will not run for ever but you will have to write code to start a new workflow execution after some time. Refer to continuous workflow example provided at link below
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/continuous.html